# Migration.exe -connectionString arguments does not work doing EF migration on CI server

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to do database update of code first migration on a build server.

I read about using migration.exe from EF 6 tools, and passing misc. context and connection settings in as arguments to the `migrate.exe` call.

I want to be able to specify the connection string, default catalog and security myself directly as arguments.

The problem is that when I have specified my connection string, etc. like:

> migrate.exe Ef.Data.DLL /ConnectionString:"Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=true"  /connectionProviderName:System.Data.SqlClient /verbose

Then migrate.exe will throw an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'MyContext' could be found in the application config file

My context is defined in code like:

`public MyContext(): base("name=MyContext")`

So it expects a `MyContext` connection string like it was still trying to use an App.Config or web.config for this, but it should not, since I'm passing this information in as arguments.

If I try to specify a `ConnectionStringName` as argument `(-connectionStringName:MyContext)` along the other args. the I get:

> ERROR: Only one of /connectionStringName or /connectionString can be specified.

So I'm pretty stuck here. Cant seem to solve this one. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the provider as a parameter as well: `/connectionProviderName:"System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Its allready there and does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today.  For me, it was sorted by changing my context constructor, from this:

```
public RootContext() : base("name=MyContext")
```

to this:

```
public RootContext() : this("MyContext")
```

Having the `name=` in front of the context name **forces** the value to be found in the config otherwise it throws an error.  This is great when you're only deploying from Visual Studio because it'll helpfully throw errors if your strings don't match, but not so great when trying to automate migrations in different environments from the command line.

So, if you make this change, be careful when running your migrations in VS - if your strings don't match it'll happily continue and create a new database in LocalDB named "MyContext" without telling you that's what it did!